# How can I use a USB key to secure my application?

Tags: security, authentication

Is using a USB key to secure an application the best option? 
If it isn't, what is the best way to secure an application in the form of requiring a valid user before the application can be used?

The reason I ask this question is that a client recently asked me to make an application require a specific USB device be inserted into the system before the app can be used or run. Basically, the application is a medical software and the client sees this method of security more trusted, as the app contains sensitive data of his paients. In that case of loss, I can tell the user how to generate another security key using the app in command line mode.

Comment: Someone could steal the USB... how about iris scanning 8-)

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close this...it's a valid question. It could use some more details as to the purpose of the application and specific requirements, however,

Comment: I for one would really like to read more about this. And if someone with empirical knowledge about the pro's and con's can step up and share that'd be awesome

Comment: If your application can generate new key, it's not seem secure at all...

Comment: You cannot 'secure' your application. At best you can make it 'more secure', but hardware based security methods have now mostly been abandoned, as they contributed little to security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily an answer to the question, but a point to be considered in response to the question and comments so far...

A USB key *by itself* is not going to be more secure than password-based authentication.  It's still one-factor, it can be lost/stolen/etc.  What the client probably *actually* wants, and either doesn't know it or hasn't properly articulated it, is multi-factor authentication.  Consider these:

1. Something you know (a password, answer to a question, etc.)
2. Something you have (a USB key, time-limited key generating fob, etc.)
3. Something you are (finger print, retina scan, etc.)

Most systems use only the first one.  For added security, you add the second one.  For Mission: Impossible style high-clearance security, throw in the third one.  The idea is that any one factor can be forged, but adding new factors adds new dimensions of security which exponentially make it more difficult (rather than linearly more difficult when just replacing one factor with a "better" factor).

Comment: A common example is a physical device (a USB key or smart card) that contains a security certificate. A PIN or password is used to decrypt said certificate. In order to compromise your system, the attacker would need the device containing the certificate plus the PIN or password.

Comment: USB cryptotokens are two-factor as they require a PIN to be used. So lost/stolen case is still covered by the password.

Comment: @Eugene: Generally, yes.  But that understanding didn't seem to be present in the question, and potentially not in the client.  I figured I'd make the point of multi-factor authentication more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Your application could require a certificate, signed by you, to be present on a regular USB memory stick. The certificate could be locked with a password, that the user would have to enter. Certificates on stolen or lost thumbdrives could be revoked.

For a less homebrew solution, I'm sure there are commercial smart card based services you could use.